# Julia date as column name

Tags: dataframe, date, julia

I am building a data frame and I wish to use Julia's Dates as the name of a column, is that possible?

that is if I have a dataframe

`df = DataFrame(); df.DateTime(2013)=2:4`

which returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataFrame`'s column identifiers are `Symbol`s so you need to convert `DateTime` to a `Symbol`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame();

julia> df[!, Symbol(DateTime(2013))] = 2:4;

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ 2013-01-01T00:00:00 │
│     │ Int64               │
├─────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2                   │
│ 2   │ 3                   │
│ 3   │ 4                   │
```

This will also work with `String`s with the same result:

```
julia> df[!, string(DateTime(2014))] = 12:14;

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ 2013-01-01T00:00:00 │ 2014-01-01T00:00:00 │
│     │ Int64               │ Int64               │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2                   │ 12                  │
│ 2   │ 3                   │ 13                  │
│ 3   │ 4                   │ 14                  │
```

Finally note that  `df[:colname]` syntax is depreciated in favor of `df[!, :colname]` but in order to find it out you need to start Julia with:

```
julia --depwarn=yes
```